# How to provide parameters to children functions in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set up the ripple effect with react using the react-water-wave package.
https://github.com/xxhomey19/react-water-wave

I am able to call child methods with no parameters and it works fine. But when I call with arguments to the parameterised drop method, nothing happens.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Background from "../img/home.jpg";
import WaterEffect from "react-water-wave";


class HomeComp extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <WaterEffect
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          height: "100vh",
          backgroundSize: "cover",
          background: `url(${Background}) no-repeat center center fixed`
        }}
        dropRadius={20}
        perturbance={0.01}
        interactive={true}
      >
        {({ drop }) => <button onClick={drop(50, 50, 20, 0.05} />}
      </WaterEffect>
    );
  }
}

export default HomeComp;
```

I need to make the ripples at certain points on the canvas. Please help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass a function as a prop, you don't want it to get called when you pass it, you want it to get called when it gets clicked/hovered/whatever.  So instead of using

```
{({ drop }) => <button onClick={drop(50, 50, 20, 0.05} />}
```

which calls it right away, try

```
{({ drop }) => <button onClick={() => drop(50, 50, 20, 0.05)} />}
```

which passes a function that is waiting to get called when your button is clicked.

Comment: Thanks it worked out! The drop takes in an object though so I got it using the following code: 
`{({ drop }) => (<button onClick={() => drop({ x: 250, y: 250, radius: 20, strength: 0.05 })} />)}`

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass parameters as props and then make your handler a lambda, e.g.

```
function Example({ a, b, c }) {
  return <ChildComp handler={() => func(a, b, c)} />;
}
```